# How to do multiply input image with matrix in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

here i am taking one image and one simple matrix , i want to multiply them and the result what i get,i want to show as image.. how can i do this thing?

here little bit my tried code in tensorflow, i don't know it is true or not

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/7seven.jpg"))
tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
c = tf.segment_sum(image, tf.constant([0, 0, 1]))
```

Comment: Try `tf.matmul` if you want to do matrix multiplication.

Comment: ya i tried that one also but it is not working for this

Comment: `image* tf.constant([0, 0, 1], dtype=tf.float32)`

Comment: @Khushi. what error are you getting in `tf.matmul`?